# what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net

like this:

```
Replace$("EG000000", "0", "")
```

Answer (score 47):

Old type notifier - [see this](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html)

Some other old ones:

```
& -> Long
% -> Integer
# -> Double
! -> Single
@ -> Decimal
$ -> String
```

Still exist in VB.Net for the sake of backward compatibility...

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: What you are referencing is Type Characters, which make dim s$ and dim s as string the same.  See Heinzi's answer.

Comment: Not correct. Heinzi's explanation is the correct one.

Answer (score 31):

In "classic" VB, there were two versions of the built in-string functions. Let me use `Left` as an example:

- `Left(s, length)` takes a *variant* as the first parameter and returns a *variant*.
- `Left$(s, length)` takes a *string* as the first parameter and returns a *string*.

This distinction still exists in modern-day VBA.

I suspect that the reason behind this is that strings in VBA cannot be `Null` (note that `Null <> ""`). Thus, when dealing with nullable database fields, you had to use variant variables. *Variant* variables can take any value, including all of the integral values (strings, integers, ...) as well as some special values such as `Null`, `Empty` or `Missing`. The non-$ functions allowed you to use variants as input and get variants as output. For example, `Left(Null, ...)` returns `Null`.

In VB.NET, this distinction is no longer necessary: The non-$ functions do exactly the same as the $ functions, which are kept only for backwards compatibility with old code.

Comment: plus one for the `VBA` reference.

Answer (score 6):

What Heinzi said and to clear up the type character business

```
    Dim s$ = "FooBar" 'dim s as String = "FooBar"

    Dim r As String
    Stop

    r = Replace$(s, "Bar", "")
    '.Net equivalent
    r = s.Replace("Bar", "")
```