# BASIC: What does an exclamation mark at the end of a function name mean?

Tags: basic

```
DECLARE FUNCTION AanUit! (Baan AS INTEGER, Aktie AS INTEGER)
DECLARE FUNCTION fVraagStatus! (Baan AS INTEGER)
DECLARE FUNCTION fMelding! (Tekst AS STRING, Warning AS INTEGER)

FUNCTION fVraagStatus (VraagBaan AS INTEGER)
  ´ retrieve status somewhere
  fVraagStatus = False or True
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION fMelding (Tekst AS STRING, Warning AS INTEGER)
  ´ locate (move cursor), print stuff
END FUNCTION
```

**My Question:** What does an exclamation mark at the end of a function name mean?

I am rewritting an old program to .net and came across something weird and i want to understand why there is a '!' at the end of the function decleration. I don't really need to write my own code, it's Just for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the function returns a `SINGLE`. Exclamation point is a shortcut for `As Single`.

Comment: Thnx: that was way faster then trying to find what the exclemation mark means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision

Comment: If what you say is true, then there are some design flaws. AanUit body isnt even in the file and has no calls to it. fMelding doesn't return anything, only printing stuff to the screen. fVraagStatus is return a boolean that i would think be translated to 0.0 and 1.0. I think im just gonna throw this one on the designer :D

Comment: Last comment: Found what i need in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341524/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-after-a-method-name-in-vb-net. There is the entire list of old notifiers.

Comment: @BobvanBokkem You didn't specify the BASIC dialect so that could have been something earlier than VisualBasic.  QBasic for instance, which has no boolean type.  Any number other than 0 means true, but the result if comparison operators isn't 1, it's -1, because NOT doubles as bitwise operator negating all bits in the integer value of its operand.