# VB.Net $ in end of string

Tags: vb.net, string

I came across the following VB.Net code:

```
Dim Test as String = "9999"
Dim Test2 as String = Test$
```

What does `$` mean in a string's name, such as is used in the second line?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a Type Notifier, which identifies the usage of `Test` as a string.

See also:

http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html

[what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341524/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-after-a-method-name-in-vb-net)

Comment: hummmmmmmmm understood