# What mean «String$» in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Got strange Access project, where found this line:

```
strUserName = String$(39, 0)
```

What `String$` means?

Comment: I guess "String" refers to a value type and "$" is a reference to target a particular information (ie. in the cell 39,0).
So it could mean... get the value at cell 39,0 and interpret it as a String to initialize the username.

String usually refers to a "character-based" type which is convenient to store words, sentence, ...

Comment: string means a string of length x of character y, so string (5,33)="!!!!!", thats 39 chr(0)'s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341524/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-after-a-method-name-in-vb-net)

Comment: @Chrismas007: depends on whether the question was mainly about the `$` or about the (rarely used) `String()` function.

Comment: I don't agree that this **VBA** question should be closed as a duplicate of a **VB.Net** question.

Comment: Simply looking in the VBA Help / Language Reference would have turned up this information. On StackOverflow you are expected to do some basic research...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What String$ means?

`String$()` means almost the same as `String()`, but `String()` can accept and return a Variant and `String$()` can not.

For example, `String()` will accept Null for the *character* argument and return Null ...

```vb
? String(5, Null)
Null
```

But substituting `String$()` for `String()` triggers error 94, *"Invalid use of Null"* ...

```vb
? String$(5, Null)
```

Regarding your example ... `String$(39, 0)` ... that returns a string of 39 null-byte characters (`Chr(0)`), which is not the same as Null.

Answer (score 2):

It's an inbuilt function, normally used without the `$`:

```
String(number, character)
```

It returns a string with `<number>` characters.

E.g. `String(5, "A")` -> AAAAA

Apparently you can also use the Ascii code for `character`, so your example returns 39 * Chr(0).

Answer (score 0):

string means a string of length x of character y, so string (5,33)="!!!!!", thats 39 chr(0)'s